# Ubuntu 14.04 Dist-Upgrade: "TypeError"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

Good time of the day! I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04, but the following Error appears:

```
ub14:~$ do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1 265 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1 266 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ohuj5xpk/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ohuj5xpk/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 228, in main
    from .DistUpgradeController import DistUpgradeController
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ohuj5xpk/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .DistUpgradeQuirks import DistUpgradeQuirks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ohuj5xpk/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 36, in <module>
    from janitor.plugincore.manager import PluginManager
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ohuj5xpk/janitor/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

All the needed stuff is done:

```
ub14:~$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
ub14:~$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

<- it's Ok.

The most possible reason of the problem: Once I've tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04, but forgot to restart the system before battery have been totally discharged. Since then `TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'` appears every time on trying to update. Update from GUI also is impossible - it's just close the window on pressing "Upgrade"-button, and it's all. Probably, anybody already have resolved the same issue, and this info could be usefull.

Is there any way to solve the problem without any side-effects further in the future (I know about the trick with changing `MARKER_EXPR()` to `MARKER_EXPR("")`, but there is no info about the side-effects during the upgrade-process or after it)? Thank You in advance!

Comment: Dear colleague, that's a pity thing, what you've down-voted the question, but didn't give an answer.
Nevertheless, the Question is still actual, and answer or even Any Suggestion could be Very Useful and even Highly Needful, so still waiting for the help! Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Doing `sudo pip uninstall pyparsing` and then `sudo pip install pyparsing` solved it for me.

Comment: Thank You very much! It looks like exactly what's needed.